# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: !checked in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script in a Website with jquery 1.7.

```
$('input:radio[name=article-info]:!checked').parent().parent().removeClass('highlight')
```

I move this script in a bootstrap template but the chrome console report me this error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:radio[name=article-info]:!checked

Bootstrap use a update version of jQuery .

What should I use syntax for this version?

The complete code:

```
// Select input radio button
        $('input[type=radio][name=article-info]').change(function() {

               $('input:radio[name=article-info]:not(:checked)').parent().parent().removeClass('highlight');
               $(this).parent().parent().addClass('highlight');

               // Price
               $price = $('label[for="'+ $(this).attr('id') +'"] .tr-price').text();
               $('#price-total').text($price);

               // Url btn
               $new_url = $(this).parent().siblings('.format').children().children('input').val();
               $('#btn-personalizar').attr("href", $new_url);
         });
//Select tr
        $(".data-click-tr").click(function(){


               $(".data-click-tr").removeClass('highlight')
               $(this).addClass('highlight').find('input:radio[name=article-info]').attr('checked', true);

               $get_input_id = $(this).find('input:radio[name=article-info]').val();

               // Precio
               $price = $('label[for="'+ $get_input_id +'"] .tr-price').text();
               $('#price-total').text($price);

               // Url btn personalizar
               $new_url = $(this).find('.format').children().children('input').val();
               $('#btn-personalizar').attr("href", $new_url);
         });
```

The HTML:

```
<table id="select-size">
    <thead class="size-and-price">
        <tr class="header-table">
            <th colspan="2">Tamaño</th>
            <th class="">Precio</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="data-click-tr highlight" data-click-tr="1426">
            <td class="input">
                <input id="1426" type="radio" name="article-info" value="1426" checked="checked">
            </td>
            <td class="format">
                <label for="">720X1080 mm <a href="//localhost:3000/manta-polar-75x100/1426">(ver ficha)</a>
                <input class="url-designs" type="hidden" value="//localhost:3000/modelos/manta-polar-75x100/1426">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="price">
                <label for="1426">
                <span class="tr-price"> 39&nbsp;€</span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data-click-tr" data-click-tr="6685">
            <td class="input">
                <input id="6685" type="radio" name="article-info" value="6685">
            </td>
            <td class="format">
                <label for="">950X1400 mm <a href="//localhost:3000/manta-polar-95x140/6685">(ver ficha)</a>
                <input class="url-designs" type="hidden" value="//localhost:3000/modelos/manta-polar-95x140/6685">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="price">
                <label for="6685">
                <span class="tr-price"> 49&nbsp;€</span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data-click-tr" data-click-tr="710">
            <td class="input">
                <input id="710" type="radio" name="article-info" value="710">
            </td>
            <td class="format">
                <label for="">1200X1900 mm <a href="//localhost:3000/manta-polar-120x190/710">(ver ficha)</a>
                <input class="url-designs" type="hidden" value="//localhost:3000/modelos/manta-polar-120x190/710">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="price">
                <label for="710">
                <span class="tr-price"> 69&nbsp;€</span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data-click-tr" data-click-tr="2259">
            <td class="input">
                <input id="2259" type="radio" name="article-info" value="2259">
            </td>
            <td class="format">
                <label for="">2400X1600 mm <a href="//localhost:3000/manta-polar-160x240-queen/2259">(ver ficha)</a>
                <input class="url-designs" type="hidden" value="//localhost:3000/modelos/manta-polar-160x240-queen/2259">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="price">
                <label for="2259">
                <span class="tr-price"> 89&nbsp;€</span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is a Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!` operator cannot be used in the selectors.

You can use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to invert the selector.

```
$(':radio[name="article-info"]:not(:checked)')...
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `:not(:checked)` part in the selector will select the radio buttons which are unchecked.

Comment: Mmm this not report any error in console but not detect the not checked inputs...

Comment: @FunnyFrontend [This works!](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/g8dfaL89/). You might be missing something else.

Comment: @FunnyFrontend **[That Works](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/qcwm9qpq/1/)** The same code in the question. Saying again, _there must be something else that might be causing the problem_

Comment: aaahhh, I edit the main post twice, You can see the //Select tr script, this fails!

Comment: I accept your answer, but Can you help with with the //Select tr?

Answer (score 1):

To add a negative control, you must use `:not()`

```
 $('input:radio[name=article-info]:not(:checked)').parent().parent().removeClass('highlight')
```

Comment: This must work, but maybe the `.parent().parent().removeClass()` section is wrong. I don't know what HTML you have for this.